# Removing the Duplicate values from a JSON object using JS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have the following JSON object

```
var array = [{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-20"},
        {"id":"1","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-21"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-19"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-03-20"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-03-19"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-01-19"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-05-20"}]
```

And I want to have the following output by removing duplicates of date related to each id

```
var outPut= [{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-21"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-19"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-03-19"}]
```

I wrote the following code which will remove duplicate values of date but then it will remove the same date of two different ids which is wrong. how can I get the expected output?

```
const uniqueAddresses = Array.from(new Set(array.map(a => a.date)))
 .map(date=> {
   return addresses.find(a => a.date=== date)
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using es6

```js
var array = [{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-20"},
        {"id":"1","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"1","date":"2019-01-21"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-19"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"2","date":"2019-03-20"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-01-20"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-03-19"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-01-19"},{"id":"3","date":"2019-05-20"}]
        
var newArr = array.filter((curr, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((elem) => (
    elem.id === curr.id && elem.date === curr.date
  ))
)

console.log(newArr);
```